# Dynamic class name with value and pipe

Tags: css, angular

I am using Weather Icons dynamically with weather api. I want icons to change dynamically, because I don't want a switch with 5+ options. I'm having trouble with creating scss class dynamically.

```
<i [class]="'wi wi-day-' + '{{weather.daily.weathercode[0] | lowercase}}'"></i>
<i class="wi wi-day-thunderstorm" ></i>
"'wi wi-day-' + '{{weather.daily.weathercode[0] | lowercase}}'"
```

Line 2 shows a thunderstorm icon, line 3 prints "'wi-wi-day-' + 'thunderstorm'". For this reason, I don't understand why 1 line didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `[]` and `{{}}` notations:

Either use:

```
<i class="wi wi-day-{{weather.daily.weathercode[0] | lowercase}}"></i>
```

or

```
<i [class]="'wi wi-day-' + (weather.daily.weathercode[0] | lowercase)"></i>
```